# time() returns correct value, but date('O') - incorrect timezone

Tags: php, timezone

The issue appeared after Russia began to live on GMT+4.

My hoster's server time is Europe/Moscow.

When I print from PHP date('d/m/Y H:i'), it returns correct Moscow timed.

But when I try to get difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours with the help of date('O'), I get +0300 (should be +0400, I think. Look here: http://localtimes.info/Europe/Russia/Moscow/Moscow/ - *Current time zone offset:  +04:00 hours*).

Question: why? Is it me doing smth wrong or it is hoster's problem?

Comment: I think the server needs to update the timezone.db: http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb

Comment: See as well: http://en.ria.ru/russia/20111030/168271560.html

Answer (score 1):

The correct UTC offset for [**Moscow Time**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Time) is `UTC +0400`:

> In 2011, the Russian government proclaimed that daylight saving time would in future be observed all year round, thus effectively displacing standard time—an action which the government claimed emerged from health concerns attributed to the annual shift back-and-forth between standard time and daylight saving time.[<sup>[1]</sup>](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/russia-winter-time.html) On 27 March 2011, Muscovites set their clocks forward for a final time, effectively observing MSD, or UTC+4, permanently.

I assume this is related to the underlying libraries of the timezone.db, or the server system itself. Try this test-script ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/A1k8Jc)):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
echo date('d/m/Y H:i O'), "\n";
echo 'timezone default: ', date_default_timezone_get(), "\n";
echo 'timezone version: ', timezone_version_get();
```

Example output:

```
05/11/2011 22:39 +0400
timezone default: Europe/Moscow
timezone version: 0.system
```

If it shows wrong values on your server, contact your administrator and/or update the system.

**Edit:** This test-script makes use of a PHP 5.3 function: [`timezone_version_get`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-version-get.php). The output with installed pecl timezonedb is:

```
05/11/2011 23:17 +0400
timezone default: Europe/Moscow
timezone version: 2011.14
```

Comment: Ran it and got:

05/11/2011 23:05 +0300
timezone default: Europe/Moscow
timezone version: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function  timezone_version_get()

So, I think, it is not my fault :) Will contact my hoster administrator! thx!

Comment: Ups, I should have checked the PHP version as well :).